# How Can Get CallbackData in current when InlineKeyboardCallbackButton clicked in telegram Bot in C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

How can I get InlineKeyboardCallbackButton clicked in telegram bot?

Here is my code : **I Edited The Code**

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> GetMsgAsync()
     {
     var req = Request.InputStream; 
     var responsString = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd(); 
     var update = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Update>(responsString);
     var message = update.Message;  
     var chat = message.Chat;  


  InlineKeyboardMarkup categoryInlineMarkup = new 
      InlineKeyboardMarkup(
         new InlineKeyboardButton[][]
                        {
                        new InlineKeyboardButton[]
                            {
                  new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("button1","callbackData")
                            }
                        }
                           );

                await api.SendTextMessageAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, "Please click the button", replyMarkup: categoryInlineMarkup);

                if (update.Type == Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.UpdateType.MessageUpdate)
                {
                    // all codes just run in this block
                }



                if (update.Type == Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.UpdateType.CallbackQueryUpdate)
                {
                    // I can't get clicked button here 
                    if (update.CallbackQuery.Data.Contains("callbackData"))
                    {
                        await api.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(update.CallbackQuery.Id, update.CallbackQuery.Data);
                    }
                }


   }
```

How can I get this button clicked also in webhook method, not in console program?

Comment: what do you mean by "getting a button clicked" ?
are you asking how you can get the response when someone clicks the button ?

Comment: yes of course , exactly! but in Webhook Model in telegram that use api server, have you any solution?

Comment: have you managed to receive the json from telegram servers ? if not a quick search can give you the answer.
after that you just need to check if `callback_query` field is present in the received json.

Comment: yes i can get server response , the main problem is that i can't get callback_query , here is all of my code : My Project is MVC in VS 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally i find out the answer, the problem is this line of code :**

```
  var message = update.Message;
```

> this line of code is the main problem because this line is not in try
>   catch block and i can't understand which line is the problem .

**After this Problem, i have a suggestion for you

You can debugging your telegram bot in your personal computer without uploading any code on any host,  for this purpose You can run 3 below steps ::**

[1- Accessing an IIS Express site from a remote computer](http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer)

[2- Download NGROK](https://ngrok.com/download)

3- after download ngrok you can forward telegram webhook requests to your personal computer  .